# Property 'level' does not exist on type 'never[]'.ts(2339) but it does log

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic2

I'm unsure why this is giving me an error I know there's something I'm meant to do but I can't figure out what to tell it not to give me an error. If I run it, it gives me an error BUT it does actually still work so the value does log in the console.

```
const Tab1: React.FC = () => {
  const [lockdownData, setLockdownData] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let finalLockdownData: any;
    var getLockdownData = async () => {
      await firestoreDB.collection("LockdownStatus").doc("lockdownData").get().then((doc) => {
        finalLockdownData = doc.data();
      });
      setLockdownData(finalLockdownData);
    };
    getLockdownData();
  }, []);
  
  console.log('Position 1')
  console.log(lockdownData?.level) //ERROR: Property 'level' does not exist on type 'never[]'.ts(2339)
  console.log('Position 2')

  return (
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write it like this

```
const [lockdownData, setLockdownData] = useState<any[]>([])
```

**Edit 1**

```js
if (lockdownData === null) {
    console.log('data is nullable');
} else {
    console.log(lockdownData!.level);
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
const [lockdownData, setLockdownData] = useState<Record<string, never>>({});
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-water-v0vwb?file=/src/App.tsx:108-184

Comment: This didnt work, however, the [] shouldnt be there anyways sorry about that

Comment: Still gives the same error `Property 'level' does not exist on type 'any[]'`

Comment: And if I make it the useState() blank it says `Property 'level' does not exist on type 'never'`

Comment: why do you want to set the initial state blank? you are using typescript

Comment: I dont want to set it blank but I am waiting to get data from a firestore DB, then once the data is retrieved I can manipulate it

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!